# How to Declare Public instance of Application.Worksheetfunction?

Tags: excel, vba, global-variables, declaration

I want to declare application.worksheetfunction as a public variable WF.

I tried:

```
Public WF As WorksheetFunction
```

This returns

> runtime error 91, "object variable or with block variable not set"

I tried:

```
Public WF As application.WorksheetFunction
```

This returns

> compile error Type Mismatch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why you would do such a thing. There might be a reason I don't understand, so:

```
Public WF As WorksheetFunction

Sub AnInitMethodOfSomeKind()
    Set WF = WorksheetFunction
End Sub
```

But, please don't. It is bad.

Comment: Hi, 
What I meant was without using a set in another sub routine, yes if that needs to be set, almost impossible in my code. As the variable could be called from different routines.